# Как в Intellij IDEA включить подсветку ожидаемых (предполагаемых) типов?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, типы

Собсвтенно, в теме и на изображении все написано. См пример на фото
[image: put-in-high-low]

Comment: как по мне, чем чаще тип указывается явно, тем понятней код. При просмотре кода с использованием других программ/сервисов (например, в github) данный способ не сработает.

Comment: Используйте такой принцип: если вам нужен хинт типа, то прописывайте тип в коде.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Inlay Hints` -> `Kotlin` галочка Show local variable type hints

Comment: Пока делал скриншоты для ответа, уже появился ответ)

Comment: Если хотите, можете добавить в ответ: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J1dV.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3jRT.png

Comment: Да нет, спасибо - уж очень они громоздкие, да и проще сразу в поиске текст забить.